# How to make a create table in Oracle PLSQ statement using variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have about 20 statements to create tables. Every year the data changes. How can I declare a variable at the top of the SQL window in Oracle and use that in each create statement.

```
Declare
      new_yr number(5) := 2015;
BEGIN

create table my_table as
select new_yr as yr,
       t.index,
       t.xcode,  
      .........
.........
......
from acccounts t
Join persons a on a.new_yr=(new_yr-t.new_yr)
group by t.index,
         t.xcode;
```

That code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try using a different name than an existing column alias. Rename your new_yr variable as v_new_yr

Comment: I did that and get ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a Dynamic `CTAS` Script and issuing an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement.

P.S. Not sure if you'll join all your tables to the table `PERSONS`, so just edit as necessary.

```
Declare

        new_yr_var  varchar2(100) := 2015;

        cursor  tbl_names
        is
        select  owner
            ,   Table_name
        from    dba_tables
        where   table_name in  ('your_table_names_here');

        sql_statement := varchar2(4000);

BEGIN

    for c1 in tbl_names loop;

        sql_statement := 'CREATE TABLE '||C1.owner||'.'||C1.Table_name||'_'||new_yr_var||' AS ';
        sql_statement := sql_statement||'SELECT COLUMNS_HERE FROM'||C1.owner||'.'||C1.Table_name||'Join persons a on a.new_yr=(new_yr-t.new_yr) ';         
        sql_statement := sql_statement||'group by t.index, t.xcode';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql_statement);

    end loop;

END;
```